# Tilestache VecTile Encoding Error

Tags: python-2.7, vector-tiles, tilestache, unicode, typeerror

I'm trying to fix what I believe to be an encoding issue with Tilestache and was curious if someone else has seen this issue.

Here's an example of the string that gets passed: 
�9*y��c�ަ��uSA��ٍ�c��'��uSA

Though when I print it out it looks like: "\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\xab9*y\xac\xd8c\xc1\xde\xa6\xd2\x19\x8duSA\x1a\xe2\xd2\xd9\x8d\xd8c\xc1\x03\x94'\x9f\x97uSA"

I have to imagine this is just my unfamiliarity with Python 2 unicode issues.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/VirtEnvs/gismaps27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 193, in run_wsgi
execute(self.server.app)
File "/VirtEnvs/gismaps27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 181, in execute
application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
File "/VirtEnvs/gismaps27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/TileStache/init.py", line 409, in call
status_code, headers, content = requestHandler2(self.config, path_info, query_string, script_name)
File "/VirtEnvs/gismaps27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/TileStache/init.py", line 285, in requestHandler2
status_code, headers, content = layer.getTileResponse(coord, extension)
File "/VirtEnvs/gismaps27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/TileStache/Core.py", line 450, in getTileResponse
tile.save(buff, format, **save_kwargs)
File "/VirtEnvs/gismaps27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/TileStache/Goodies/VecTiles/server.py", line 329, in save
mvt.encode(out, features)
File "/VirtEnvs/gismaps27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/TileStache/Goodies/VecTiles/mvt.py", line 81, in encode
wkb = approximate_wkb(feature[0])
File "/VirtEnvs/gismaps27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/TileStache/Goodies/VecTiles/wkb.py", line 142, in approximate_wkb
input, output = StringIO(wkb_in), StringIO()
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str
```

Comment: What's your code you use? What's the GIS software ?